# Exception warning in Haskell, but not with OldException

Tags: exception, haskell

Why does this code work with

```
import qualified Control.OldException as E
```

but not with

```
import qualified Control.Exception as E
```

Here is the code:

```
    fileContents <- (readFile "shpm.txt") `E.catch` (\_ -> return "")
```

Here is the error I get with the "new" Exception

```
Ambiguous type variable `e0' in the constraint:
  (E.Exception e0) arising from a use of `E.catch'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  fileContents <- (readFile "shpm.txt")
                  `E.catch` (\ _ -> return "No Tasks")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the types have changed.  Specifically:

- OldException: `catch :: IO a -> (Exception -> IO a) -> IO a`
- Exception: `catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a`

The new model needs to know what the value of `e` is for the `Exception e` type.  What this means practically is that you need to tell the compiler which exception you are catching.  Your example with `OldException` catches everything, which is now discouraged (see [Catching All Exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#g:4) for more info).

A simple fix to your function would be something like this:

```
foo = (readFile "foo") `E.catch` (\e -> const (return "") (e :: E.IOException))
```

Or the lambda-less version:

```
bar = (readFile "foo") `E.catch` myHandler

myHandler :: E.IOException -> IO String
myHandler _ = return ""
```

Comment: This worked great, I understand it all except for the "const", what did that do?

Comment: @hatboysam `const` just takes two args and returns the first ("throwing away" the second arg).  That just gave me a way to give an inline declaration of `e`'s type (without actually using the value of `e`).  I only thought of that first, since it was a direct modification of your example, but the second example is much clearer and probably what you should use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an explict type for the exception being caught.  For example:

```
fileContents <- (readFile "shpm.txt") `E.catch` ((\_ -> return "") :: E.SomeException -> IO String)
```

Comment: I think you have a stray `::` there.